# Syntax for expanding a tuple used in an enum when using a switch statement

Tags: swift, enums

Consider I have an enum with 2 cases, one of which has a tuple:

```
enum MyEnum {
  case FirstCase(output: (someString:  String, someInt: Int))
  case SecondCase(error: ErrorType)
}
```

When I create an enum constant:

```
let myEnum = MyEnum.FirstCase(output: (someString: "myString", someInt: 3))
```

I can use a switch statement and do something on each case

```
switch myEnum {
case .FirstCase(let output):
  print(output.someInt) // prints 3
  // OR
  let (someString, someInt) = output
  print(someInt) // prints 3
case .SecondCase(let error):
  print(error)
}
```

The following code has a compiler error. How can I expand the tuple inside the case? Is this is a syntax issue or a limitation of Swift?

```
switch myEnum {
case .FirstCase(let (someString, someInt)): // This causes a compiler error " Tuple pattern has the wrong length for tuple type '(output: (someString: String, someInt: Int))'"
  print(someInt)
case .SecondCase(let error):
  print(error)
}
```

**Update:**

This gets close but the `output:` seems pointless

```
switch myEnum {
case .FirstCase(output: (let someString, let someInt)):
  print(someInt) // prints 3
case .SecondCase(let error):
  print(error)
}
```

**Update 2 from vacawama's answer**

The syntax actually makes sense since I could have

```
enum OtherEnum {
  case FirstCase(output: (someString:  String, someInt: Int), outputB: (someString:  String, someInt: Int))
  case SecondCase(error: ErrorType)
}

let otherEnum = OtherEnum.FirstCase(output: (someString: "myString", someInt: 3), outputB: (someString: "myString", someInt: 3) )


switch otherEnum {
case .FirstCase(output: (let someString, let someInt), outputB: (let someStringB, let someIntB)):
  print(someString)
case .SecondCase(let error):
  print(error)
}
```

So if I wanted to remove the `output:` I would do:

```
enum SimpleEnum {
  case FirstCase(someString: String, someInt: Int)
  case SecondCase(error: ErrorType)
}

let simpleEnum = SimpleEnum.FirstCase(someString: "myString", someInt: 3)

switch simpleEnum {
case .FirstCase(let someString, let someInt):
  print(someString)
case .SecondCase(let error):
  print(error)
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to expand the tuple inside the case?

Comment: I think it is more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to your **Update:** answer:

```
case .FirstCase(output: let (someString, someInt)):
```

and

```
case let .FirstCase(output: (someString, someInt)):  // thanks @MartinR
```

work as well.

By having the `output:` label in your `enum` case, you have created a named tuple of one value containing a named tuple of two values.  If you don't specify `output:` in the `switch`, Swift is going to attempt to match the outer tuple with the tuple you supply and the count of the items doesn't match.

Providing the `output:` label in the pattern allows Swift to know that you are talking about the inner tuple, and it then works.

If you feel `output:` is pointless, why include it in your enum definition at all?

Comment: Or `case let .FirstCase(output: (someString, someInt)):`

Comment: Thanks, @MartinR, I added that to the answer.

Comment: My original example use a generic, i.e. `case Success(output: T)`.  I agree with what you said, if I think it is pointless I should remove the `output:` altogether. Also I noticed that the syntax makes since I could have multiple tuple parameters. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Putting `let` in front seems to be the most universal solution, it works in all cases (!), with named and unnamed tuples. I have the feeling that this was covered in some Xcode release notes, but cannot find it anymore.